# Calculation of variance in boundary cases of constrained likelihood

Tags: variance, maximum-likelihood

I am computing the MLE values of some parameters of a likelihood function, subject to non-negativity constraints. Given these constraints, some of the MLE values for my parameters are exactly in the boundary (i.e. they are equal to zero). Is it still valid to estimate the variance of the MLEs using the Hessian of the likelihood function, even in these boundary cases?

Comment: Look up references in this post, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/68864/general-theorems-for-consistency-and-asymptotic-normality-of-maximum-likelihood/68866#68866