# When does asymptotic normality of the Bayesian posterior (Bernstein-von Mises) fail?

Tags: bayesian, asymptotics

Consider the posterior density function given (as usual) by
$$ \pi(\theta) \prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i;\theta),$$
with prior density $\pi$ and distribution $f(\cdot;\theta)$ of the $n$ observations $x_1, \dots, x_n$, conditional on the parameter value $\theta$.

Under certain conditions, the posterior distribution is asymptotically normal (a result which is known as the Bernstein-von Mises theorem, see e.g. v.d Vaart, *Asymptotic Statistics*, Section 10.2, for rigorous arguments, or Young & Smith, *Essentials of Statistical Inference*, Section 9.12, for an informal discussion.)

Are there any (hopefully elementary) examples in which the Bayesian posterior is not asymptotically normal? In particular are there examples where

1. $\pi$ and $f$ are continuously differentiable with respect to $\theta$?
2. $\pi(\theta) > 0$ for all $\theta$?

One example I noted in the literature is that where $X_1, \dots, X_n$ are independent Cauchy random variables with location parameter $\theta$. In this case, with positive probability there exist multiple local maxima of the likelihood function (See Young & Smith, Example 8.3). Perhaps this may present a problem in the B-vM theorem although I am not sure.

*Update:*
Sufficient conditions for BvM are (as stated in v.d Vaart, Section 10.2):

- data is obtained from distribution with fixed parameter $\theta_0$
- experiment is `differentiable in quadratic mean' at $\theta_0$ with non-singular Fisher information matrix $I(\theta_0)$
- the prior is absolutely continuous in a region around $\theta_0$
- the model is continuous and identifiable
- there exists a test which separates $H_0 : \theta = \theta_0$ from $H_1 : \|\theta -\theta_0\| \geq \varepsilon$ for some $\varepsilon > 0$

Comment: I think it is more relevant to whether the KL support of prior contains the TRUE parameter?

Comment: I can't find a proof, but intuition says $p(\theta)$ won't be normal even asymptotically if $\theta$ is on the boundary of the parameter space. Analogous, obviously, to [the result about maximum likelihood estimates](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/68864).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.Does the Cauchy example contradicts the Bernstein von-Mises Theorem?**

No. Bernstein von-Mises Theorem is not applicable when the joint distribution does not have a differentiable second moment. And obviously joint i.i.d. Cauchy random variables does not even have a finite second moment. This condition requires a bounded energy assumption on the Riemannian manifold defined by the Rao-Fisher metric which is not satisfied by Cauchys.

**2.Are there any (hopefully elementary) examples in which the Bayesian posterior is not asymptotically normal? In particular are there examples where
$\pi,f$ are continuously differentiable with respect to $\theta$? $\pi(\theta)>0 $ for all $\theta$?**

Yes. Indeed, we can choose an (noninformative) improper prior $\pi\propto C_0$ making the posterior also improper. For example $f\propto C_1$ is a trivial example. An improper posterior cannot be normal. For example, [Rubio&Steel] (14) provided an example where Jeffereys prior leading to an improper posterior which cannot be normal no matter how large the sample size is.

**Reference**

[Rubio&Steel]Rubio, Francisco J., and Mark FJ Steel. "Inference in two-piece location-scale models with Jeffreys priors." Bayesian Analysis 9.1 (2014): 1-22.

Comment: Thank you Henry.L, this is very useful, I will look up the reference. I am glad the question finally received some attention!

Comment: Can you give a simple example with a proper prior?